# Closure compiler doesn't remove unused properties

Tags: javascript, google-closure-compiler

```
(function(){
    var num = 4 // Math.random()
    var module1 = {};

    (function(export_to){
        export_to.add1 = function(arg) { return arg+1 }
        export_to.add2 = function(arg) { return arg+2 }
        export_to.add10 = function(arg) { return arg+10 }
    })(module1)

    console.log(module1.add10(num))
})()
```

This is primitive inline "module" example. As long as `num` is constant, GCC correctly inlines `add10` function and eliminates everything else with `--compilation_level=ADVANCED`, leaving only:

```
console.log(14);
```

as the result.

Changing `//` to `&&` though make GCC behave much worse. For some reason it no longer inlines `.add10` and no longer notices that `.add1` and  `.add2` are not called at all and effectively are dead code.

```
(function(){var d=Math.random(),c={};(function(b){b.b=function(a){return a+1};b.c=function(a){return a+2};b.a=function(a){return a+10}})(c);console.log(c.a(d))})();
```

Is there a way to make GCC eliminate/inline such functions while still keeping them inside their own `function` scope in case I'd need some private persisten variables and neatly grouped in an Object in original source? Perhaps some annotation?

This all was tested on latest available pre-built release at the moment of posting:

```
Closure Compiler (http://github.com/google/closure-compiler)
Version: v20160315
Built on: 2016/03/25 11:43
```

Comment: You probably need to find annotations to give the compiler more information, but I can't think of how to do it. Closure compiler is oriented more towards the [classical Java-style inheritance patterns](http://bolinfest.com/javascript/inheritance.php).  This way of writing modules seems to be a "new frontier" for Closure Compiler.  See https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/wiki/JS-Modules.  I hope someone with more experience with this "module style" in Closure Compiler can help you.

Comment: In my answer below I show that the latest version of Closure Compiler solves your problem. I don't know when they will make another pre-built compiler, but It is quite easy to build the compiler on your local machine.  Steps are: `git clone https://github.com/google/closure-compiler.git`, `ant jar`.

Comment: Is there anything else you need for answering this question?

Answer (score 3):

UPDATE: The latest version of Closure Compiler correctly minifies your code.  The [online Closure Compiler](http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home) is still an older version (I don't know how to tell what version it is).

This shows the version of the compiler I'm using

```
$ java -jar ../javascript/closure-compiler/build/compiler.jar --version
Closure Compiler (http://github.com/google/closure-compiler)
Version: v20160315-213-g4787bb5
Built on: 2016/04/25 10:12
```

This shows the code I'm compiling:

```
$ cat test2.js
(function(){
    var num = Math.random();
    var module1 = {};

    (function(export_to){
        export_to.add1 = function(arg) { return arg+1 }
        export_to.add2 = function(arg) { return arg+2 }
        export_to.add10 = function(arg) { return arg+10 }
    })(module1)

    console.log(module1.add10(num))
})()
```

This shows the compile command and result:

```
$ java -jar ../javascript/closure-compiler/build/compiler.jar 
    --js test2.js --compilation_level ADVANCED
console.log(Math.random()+10);
```

Below is my earlier answer (now irrelevant).

---

You are running into some limitations of Closure Compiler. Here is a quote from [Closure Compiler Issue 891: missed property collapsing opportunity](https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/issues/891)

> The issue is that "property" collapsing only happens once for global scope, and that is before function inlining occurs (within functions this occurs during the optimization loop). For this to work "collapse properties" would need to occur at least once more, or we would need to enhance the function local version to be able to run in global scope.
>
> You would need to modify DefaultPassConfig to run CollapseProperties a second time. There is not a existing compiler options to do this.

So there might be ways to modify Closure Compiler to handle your case. Here is a blog post about how to get started with modifying the compiler: [High-level overview of a compilation job](http://closuretools.blogspot.com/2016/03/high-level-overview-of-compilation-job.html)

See also [Understanding Property Removal](https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/wiki/Understanding-Property-Removal).

I'm not clear on your requirements, you seem to be using a [module pattern](http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Module-Pattern-In-Depth.html).  If you don't need that particular pattern this code works:

```
(function() {
var Adder = {};
Adder.add1 = function(arg) { return arg+1; }
Adder.add2 = function(arg) { return arg+2; }
Adder.add10 = function(arg) { return arg+10; }

console.log(Adder.add10(Math.random()));
})()
```

The result using [online Closure Compiler](http://closure-compiler.appspot.com) with Advanced Optimization is nicely minified

```
console.log(Math.random()+10);
```

But using an augmentation module pattern doesn't completely collapse the code, though it does do some inlining. Here is an example:

```
var module1 = {};
module1 = (function(export_to){
    export_to.add1 = function(arg) { return arg+1 }
    export_to.add2 = function(arg) { return arg+2 }
    export_to.add10 = function(arg) { return arg+10 }
    return export_to;
})(module1);

console.log(module1.add10(4))
```

The result with Advanced Optimization is

```
var b={},b=function(a){a.a=function(a){return a+1};a.c=function(a)
{return a+2};a.b=function(){return 14};return a}(b);console.log(14);
```

This perhaps qualifies as a [bug in the compiler](https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/issues/1757).

I suspect that your original code collapsing to `console.log(14)` is a bit of a fluke.  My guess is that the compiler does some integer arithmetic during compilation and that case just happens to work out.  Note that using a non-integer causes your original code to not collapse (same as when using `Math.random()` for the value of `num`)

```
(function(){
    var num = 4/3;
    var module1 = {};

    (function(export_to){
        export_to.add1 = function(arg) { return arg+1 }
        export_to.add2 = function(arg) { return arg+2 }
        export_to.add10 = function(arg) { return arg+10 }
    })(module1)

    console.log(module1.add10(num))
})()
```

Result:

```
(function(){var d=4/3,c={};(function(b){b.b=function(a){return a+1};
b.c=function(a){return a+2};b.a=function(a){return a+10}})(c);
console.log(c.a(d))})();
```

Comment: "As an aside," I would also caution you to "always look at the _general_ case" when writing (or using) code like this.  "Clever" as a compiler might be, it is never "intelligent."  Furthermore: anything that you tell it to do "at _any_ time," it is doomed to do _"every_ time."  If you, for instance, "modify the compiler" to handle "case-X" as you intended, the compiler will blindly _also_ apply that same mod to "cases-Y,Z, and Q!"  Perhaps this is why(!) some author ... not only chose not to implement a particular option, but explicitly chose to say so, "in detail." . . . :-/